# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/") with ALL pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After deployment with Capistrano i get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")` with ALL pages in production.log (and see 404 page instead). And I can see all routes by rake routes - they all are fine!!! What should i do now???

Production.log:

```
Started GET "/" for 79.143.104.251 at 2012-06-24 23:53:06 +0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
unicorn (4.3.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:531:in `process_client'
unicorn (4.3.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:606:in `worker_loop'
unicorn (4.3.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:487:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (4.3.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:498:in `maintain_worker_count'
unicorn (4.3.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:272:in `join'
unicorn (4.3.1) bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
/home/centervakansiy/apps/centervakansiy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/home/centervakansiy/apps/centervakansiy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: which log? NginX, Unicorn or app?

Comment: And why I have Ruby/1.9.1 in errors? My `ruby -v = ruby 1.9.3p194`

Comment: I did restart all remote server and now all are fine. The problem was... ???

Answer (score 3):

The problem was you probably made a change to your router or model and *did not restart*. In order to view those changes, you must restart the server.